# Connect to Epic Medical System via Interconnect

Tags: soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect an Epic medical system using its Interconnect Web Service offering which exposes some simple SOAP endpoints.  http://userweb.epic.com gives very little information other than a list of services and some sample XML.

I managed to get at a test wsdl and using SoapUI made a test call with no luck.

The Interconnect status page says all is well and that the service is available.

So my questions are

(i) How do I get to dynamically generated wsdls for services?

(ii) What is the URL endpoint for services.  Sending the SOAP XML request to `http://xxxxxxxxx/Interconnect-Test/` fails.

Here is my test XML request which should just add 2 numbers on the server.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:urn="urn:epicsystems-com:Interconnect.2004-05.Services.Diagnostics">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:AddRemote>
         <urn:int1>1</urn:int1>
         <urn:int2>2</urn:int2>
      </urn:AddRemote>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: For future visitors looking for help with Epic web services, there is [an official support forum](https://userweb.epic.com/AppOrchard) that is monitored by Epic staff.

Answer (score 3):

So the magic seems to be that you need to have "Config Editor" installed on the Interconnect server and then enable "Developer View".

The status view now has a developer link on the top right side.  Clicking on that gives the Web Services info and access to wsdl's.  Some services also offer REST as well as SOAP.

The wsdl's are badly formed and you will need to add a service tag to get it to work in something like java's wsimport.